# How to get syntax highlighting/colors in the internal terminal in VIM?

Tags: vim, terminal, syntax-highlighting

I tried googling this but google doesn't understand what I want. This probably is a duplicate, sorry about that! I recently learned about the editor VIM and decided to use it for writing some Rust code.

Inside VIM I want to have a split screen of my Rust code on the left and the integrated terminal on the right (the one you get by executing `:term` or `:terminal` in normal mode). The left side works like I want it, with syntax highlighting (using [gruvbox](https://github.com/gruvbox-community)) as per definition in my `.vimrc` file.
[image]
Cargo highlights errors and warnings nicely in the terminal on its own. How can I get the terminal side to also show syntax highlighting/colored text, as in the terminal output from ubuntu?
[image]

If this is not possible in VIM, how can I create a split screen between my code in VIM and a 'real' terminal?

**EDIT:** I tried changing to Neovim and it works there!

Comment: On my vim, it is displaying the colors perfectly in its integrated terminal. I see from the screenshot that bold text is still bold in the terminal, so vim is interpreting the ansi escape codes... Can you try switching to some different colorschemes to see if gruvbox somehow overrides things?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was gruvbox. :(